# Angular - applying filter in real time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filtering

I have an array of objects:

```
[{
  name: "test",
  type: 0,
  speed: 50
}, {
  name: "test2",
  type: 4,
  speed: 10
}, {
  name: "test3",
  type: 4,
  speed: 67
}, {
  name: "test4",
  type: 2,
  speed: 40
}]
```

I want to show the array with ng-repeat..
Until here everything is simple...

But now I want to add few buttons, each button will filter the array with other parameters...
For example:

Button one: Show only the objects where the speed is more than X,
Button two: Show only the objects where the type is Y..
etc...

I now how to use angular filters, but I couldn't understand how to use it for my needs...

Thank you very much!

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: this seems similar to how the angularjs docs describe using `ng-repeat` and `filter` here: [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most suitable solution for your purpose it is using filter named [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). It can accept custom filtering function in argument.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items|filter:filterItem"></div>
```

Then you should define function `filterItem` in your controller:

**JS**

```
// assume that first button sets `$scope.hideSlow` flag and the second `$scope.showType` respectively
$scope.filterItem = function(item) {
    return (!$scope.hideSlow || item.speed > X) &&
       (!$scope.showType || item.type === Y);
}
```

You can add extra filtering logic into this function, but do not forget write tests on it to be sure that your function filtering properly

Comment: But how can i change the filter when the user click a button?

Comment: Your filter function will be automatically applied with each digest

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest creating a custom filter that inspects the model to determine the result set out of the filter.  Bind the buttons to methods on the scope to check from within the filter.

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09